# Mongodb .bson import

Tags: mongodb

I am newbie to mongodb.

I have one database where collections are in .bson format and metadata is in json file. , so **how can I import this to my database.?**

My Files are :

EmployeeDetail.bson & EmployeeDetail.meatadata.json

Answer (score 0):

For Importing JSON files into mongodb try this.

```
mongoimport --db db_name --collection collection_name --type json --file file_name.json
```

And for BSON you can use mongorestore.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/backups/#ImportExportTools-mongorestore